# Problema para insertar imagen en Python

Tags: python

Hola me gustaria me ayudaran a resolver la inclusion de imagen que tengo en mi codigo, mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()

miframe=Frame(root,width=500, height=400)

miframe.pack()

Label(miframe,text="Hola Emma",fg="blue",font=50).place(x=250,y=200)

miImagen=PhotoImage(file="descarga.gif")

label2=Label(miframe,image=miImagen).place(x=100,y=20)

root.mainloop()
```

El error que tengo es que no me reconoce la linea donde declaro la imagen

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ventana2.py", line 6, in <module>
    miImagen=PhotoImage(file='descarga.gif')

_tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "descarga.gif"
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! De cual linea hablas? que error te da?

Comment: Para poder ayudarte, puedes poner mas detalles sobre el error?

Comment: @gbianchi Allí detallo la línea 6 en el error, es la linea que me da error